# Gauge in a report - is it possible?

Tags: reporting, charts

I am able to create Gauge charts within a Dashboard, but I have a need to display 2 reports in 2 different Dashboards, where the correct display/chart needs to be a Gauge.

The Gauge format is not visible in the formats of charts when in the report, anyone knows if it's possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible with default reporting. Per salesforce docs these are the only chart types available: Bar, Column, Line, Pie, Donut, Funnel, and Scatter.

http://na2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/chart_types.htm

You could create a VF page that displays all the data and groups it together into a gauge though. Check out this article on VF Charting: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/10/visualforce-charting-for-all.html